# What's the Java equivalent of Python pip install package?

Tags: java

In Python, to install a package, you can use `pip install package`. Is there a similar concept for Java and if so how does one do this? Is this done by adding a dependency to `build.gradle`? Is a library for Java the equivalent of a package in Python?

Comment: no, you can use maven or gradle.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent. The closest is adding the dependency to your Maven pom.xml, or Gradle build.gradle, but it is not directly the same. Also, don't ask multiple questions in a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a good question. Mainly because the difference between `Java` and `python`.

**Let's start at the beginning:**

When I develop via `python`, I'm using https://pypi.org/ in order to explore 3rd-party libraries. Once I find a good candidate I install it via `pip install` as mentioned in the question. Easy as pie.. thon.. I guess

In `Java` things are "slightly" different. Although the libraries in java are built the same way (as `jar` files) there are various building tools provided for `Java`. That is to say - when you ask "how to import and install a library in java?" it actually depends on you project's configuration

I, in person, loves https://mvnrepository.com/ when using `Java`. It is clear, informative and most important - it provides (for each library) various build solutions that you can easily use. Didn't find what you are looking for? Getting into trouble? You can always manually download the library `jar` file and embed it into your project (not ideal for most use-cases but - it is possible)

I attach here an image to make it clear where to find each of the options that I mentioned above in order to make more sense

Happy coding!

[image]

Comment: May I ask a follow up, what then does mvn do with the defined dependencies? `pip` literally installs the packages, does `mvn` also download and install dependencies? What confuses me most is that, when I add a `import` statement to a Java file, this doesn't imply a new dependency, right?

Comment: @TMOTTM Maven downloads to `$HOME/.m2`, similar to pip downloading to Python `site-packages`. The difference is that multiple versions of Java can use the same folder, but Python libraries are version dependent. You need classes on the JVM classpath before they can be imported

Answer (score 1):

> Is this done by adding a dependency to build.gradle

Assuming you're actually using Gradle, then yes.

Otherwise, curl/wget JAR files from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/) and `export CLASSPATH` to the location of those JARs is the closest CLI-only equivalent. This approach is error prone because it won't grab transitive dependencies.

Java libraries include packages, yes. Java modules don't work like Python modules, though.